Heavy Wooden Door With Commercial Door Closer Off Balance / Crooked
I live in a residential unit that has a heavy wooden door that is opened and closed with help from a commercial door closer.

This is a relatively new building that was finished 4 years ago.  My door has always been a little bit off balance, with the side that the lock is on always higher off of the ground than the side the latches are on.

I've looked at my neighbors' doors and noticed that my door is much more off balance than theirs.  Recently, this has caused the door harder to close and open (I suspect it's because we're in a 50 story concrete building and the structure has been slowly settling over the years).  The top of the side with the lock is seeing some scratches because the door is pushing up against it when you open / close it.

What are some of the steps I can take to fix this?  Specifically, I believe I would want to even out the leveling of the door so that the side of the door with the lock aligns more evenly (it's lower to the ground).

This is a commercial building, so the process is to notify the building management either by email or in a phone call with a request from you to have them give you the workorder number. ( this is your proof that you gave notification of an issue.)  Then the maintenance department handles the repairs or adjustments.  Have "before" pictures as you have shown here, in the event the repair doesn't meet with your satisfaction.

@RMDman small chance it could be a condo.  I'm not familiar with them since I've never owned one, but IIRC it's typically only structural parts that homeowners aren't allowed to DIY—not sure about doors though.  In (what we Americans call) an apartment, for sure it'd be building management who would deal with it.

@Huesmann,  Pics show the door goes into a common hallway.  That would indicate a commercial building, whether an apartment or condo building.  In those instances any part of the common areas is the responsibility of the managing association.  The door and door frame is part of the common area. Step inside the unit and it is personal area.
